# Android Things (Raspi 3) Wi-Fi Issue

Tags: android

Turning on Wi-Fi on Android Things device, reboots the device.

**Things Tried**

1.Tried to connect to Wi-fi through adb command also the ui.

2.Tried with and without Ethernet cable plugged to raspi.

3. Manually added the network conf in the wpa_supplicant.conf file in the raspi.
4. Tried on recent Android things (1.0.5 and 1.0.6) os

All these results in reboot of the device. It reboots continuously after the initial reboot.

Logs were also not helpful.

Is there any peculiar reason this is happening? Or am I missing anything?

Comment: Do you use an adequate power supply?

Comment: Using a 5 volt adpater? What is the adequate power supply ?

Comment: According to this the Pi consumes 250mA with enabled wifi: https://www.pidramble.com/wiki/benchmarks/power-consumption For Android that might be higher

Comment: Do you see a yellow thunder bolt on the top right side of the screen?